# When and Whether should we normalize the ground-truth labels in the multi-task regression models?

Tags: pytorch, regression, normalization, tensorflow-datasets, multitasking

I am trying a multi-task regression model. However, the ground-truth labels of different tasks are on different scales. Therefore, I wonder whether it is necessary to normalize the targets. Otherwise, the MSE of some large-scale tasks will be extremely bigger. The figure below is part of my overall targets. You can certainly find that columns like ASA_m2_c have much higher values than some others.

[image]

First, I have already tried some weighted loss techniques to balance the concentration of my model when it does gradient backpropagation. The result shows it didn't perform well.

Secondly, I have seen tremendous discussions regarding normalizing the input data, but hardly discovered any particular talking about normalizing the labels. It's partly because most of the people's problems are classification type and a single task. I do know pytorch provides a convenient approach to normalize the vision dataset by transform.normalize, which is still operated on the input rather than the labels.

Similar questions: https://forums.fast.ai/t/normalizing-your-dataset/49799

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/ground-truth-label-normalization/26981/19

[PyTorch - How should you normalize individual instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736034/pytorch-how-should-you-normalize-individual-instances)

Moreover, I think it might be helpful to provide some details of my model architecture. The input is first fed into a feature extractor and then several generators use the shared output representation from that extractor to predict different targets.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score -1):

I've been working on a Multi-Task Learning problem where one head has an output of ~500 and another between 0 and 1.
I've tried Uncertainty Weighting but in vain. So I'd be grateful if you could give me a little clue about your studies.(If there is any progress)
Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).